# python logging msecs format with {} style

Tags: python, logging, format-specifiers

For Python 3.6's logging:

I would like to get `{msecs}` to work in the format string when using `style="{"`. 
I just want 3 digits of msecs. 
However all of the following attempt has failed:
`{msecs:3.0f}`
`{msecs:03d} # this is in the official documentation and doesn't work`
what am I doing wrong here? my general impression is that `format_spec` of `str.format()` doesn't work well in the `fmt` argument

```
import logging
rl = logging.getLogger()
formatter_stdout = logging.Formatter(
    fmt='{asctime},{msecs:03d} {message}',
    style='{',
)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter_stdout)
rl.addHandler(ch)

rl.warning('asdf')
```

Comment: have you tried `f'{msecs:0.3f}'` ?

Comment: it gets weird results: `2018-01-30 03:22:28,904,904.217 asdf`

Comment: Oh, I understand now. `f'{msecs:3.0f}'` works then. But that's not a solution for your formatter problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define format for date/time as part of `fmt` argument. There's separate `datefmt` argument for this. However without defining custom `formatTime()` function you can't use it to format miliseconds, either per the following note in section [16.6.4. Formatter Objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#formatter-objects):

> *Changed in version 3.3*: Previously, the default ISO 8601 format was
>   hard-coded as in this example: `2010-09-06 22:38:15,292` where the
>   part before the comma is handled by a strptime format string
>   (`'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`), and the part after the comma is a millisecond
>   value. Because strptime does not have a format placeholder for
>   milliseconds, the millisecond value is appended using another format
>   string, `'%s,%03d'` — and both of these format strings have been
>   hardcoded into this method. With the change, these strings are defined
>   as class-level attributes which can be overridden at the instance
>   level when desired. The names of the attributes are
>   `default_time_format` (for the strptime format string) and
>   `default_msec_format` (for appending the millisecond value).

You can either format miliseconds yourself in your custom `formatTime()` function or you can make use of default implementation of this function and only set `default_msec_format` attribute of formatter object.

```
formatter_stdout.default_msec_format = '%s,%03d'
```

In `fmt` argument you refer to **already formatted** date/time by using `{asctime}` placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
fmt='{asctime}.{msecs:03.0f} …'
```

Not sure why it is using a float for msecs, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.8, you can use the `datefmt` parameter:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
logging.info('Process begins')
```

gives

```
2023-06-06 17:40:43 Process begins
```